# Vuejs - getting a querystring value into a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, query-string

I have a querystring like this:

```
https://someurl.com?q=test
```

And I have a component like so:

```
Vue.component('externalrecipes', {
props: ['results'],
template: `
    <section>
        <div class="" v-for="result in results">
            <div class="card card-similar card-external text-center">
                <img :src="result.image_url" />
                <div id="meta" class="text-center">
                    <h5>{{ result.title }}</h5>
                    <a target="_blank" :href="'https://www.wine-searcher.com/find/' + q + '/1/uk'" role="button">Buy Wine</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
`
})
```

However, this isn;t working. I want to be able to pass the value of 'q' in the querystring to this line of code:

```
<a target="_blank" :href="'https://www.wine-searcher.com/find/' + q + '/1/uk'" role="button">Buy Wine</a>
```

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Are you using vue-router?

Comment: No I'm not, I'm still pretty early on in my vue journey and I've not got to routers yet.

Comment: Seems like you have to define `q` in the context of you component, through a props or a data attribute.

Comment: OK, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: Either you add a `q` (or maybe `queryId`) prop that you init when instantiating your component. Or you use a property of your `result` item defined through the `v-for` directive

Comment: Could you show me a code example for that please?

Comment: I edited the answer with a snippet illustrating both cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the `q` variable within the component context. You can do so with props (set the value upon component instantiation) but in your use case it would make sense to retrieve its value from the `result` object used through the `v-for`.
Check the following snippet for both 'query in props' and 'query in result' examples.
You have to know/define where this query value come from. Your `results` items or the parent component

```js
Vue.component('externalrecipes_props', {
props: ['results', 'query'],
template: `
    <section>
        <div v-for="result in results">
            <div class="card card-similar card-external text-center">
                <img :src="result.image_url" />
                <div id="meta" class="text-center">
                    <h5>{{ result.title }}</h5>
                    <a target="_blank" :href="'https://www.wine-searcher.com/find/' + query + '/1/uk'" role="button">Buy Wine</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
`
});

Vue.component('externalrecipes_result', {
props: ['results'],
template: `
    <section>
        <div class="" v-for="result in results">
            <div class="card card-similar card-external text-center">
                <img :src="result.image_url" />
                <div id="meta" class="text-center">
                    <h5>{{ result.title }}</h5>
                    <a target="_blank" :href="'https://www.wine-searcher.com/find/' + result.query + '/1/uk'" role="button">Buy Wine</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
`
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <p>Include query in props</p>
    <externalrecipes_props :results="[
      {
        title: 'Some result',
        image_url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/100'
      }]" query="merlot" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Include query in results items</p>
    <externalrecipes_result :results="[
      {
        title: 'Some result',
        image_url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/100',
        query: 'merlot'
      }]" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Fred, but the top example didn;t work. The second example won;t work because that string isn;t available in the JSON object.

Comment: ok for the top example to work, you need to pass the value to the component when instantiating it `<externalrecipes :results="..." queryId="toBeInsertedInQuery" />`

Comment: Sorry Fred, that didn;t work either - is there any chance you could create a fiddle for me so I can see whats going on?